# app engine insists on binding to port 80

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to run the latest Go SDK of Google App Engine on Windows Subsystem for Linux.  I want to bind it to port 8080 but the system keeps trying to bind to port 80, and failing.

$ dev_appserver.py --port 8080 .

INFO     2018-06-08 02:48:56,648 devappserver2.py:120] Skipping SDK update check.

INFO     2018-06-08 02:48:56,786 api_server.py:274] Starting API server at: http://localhost:53314

INFO     2018-06-08 02:48:56,791 dispatcher.py:270] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080

INFO     2018-06-08 02:48:56,792 admin_server.py:152] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000

ERROR    2018-06-08 02:48:58,427 http_runtime.py:396] bad runtime process port ['2018.0608.0248.5842   listen tcp :80: bind: permission denied\n']

---

I found the problem.  I am porting this code from non-appengine Go code, and I had left "http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)" in the code.

Comment: Try `--port=8080`

Comment: To bind anything to ports less than 1024 on Windows, you need administrator access.

Comment: Please post the update as an answer, to not leave the question showing as unanswered. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I am porting this code from non-appengine Go code, and I had left "http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)" in the code.